# Is Shiny Server Open Source capable of multithreading?

Tags: r, multithreading, shiny-server, shinyproxy

I'm looking at setting up a Shiny app that uses the Furrr package behind the scenes for some multithreaded operations. While checking the documentation for Shiny Server I read that the Open Source version is limited to a single process.

Does this mean anything running on Shiny Server Open Source can't be used in conjunction with any of the multithreading packages, since afaik all multithreading in R requires creating multiple processes? Also would this apply as well to something like ShinyProxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Jcheng on github](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/issues/449#issuecomment-643919737):

> Shiny Server will launch up to one R process for each app to run Shiny, then those R processes can launch child processes if they want.

So the answer is yes shiny server open source is capable of multithreading, it simply wont automatically create new R processes to serve concurrent users' sessions (ie automatic load balancing).